# Where to report garbled files on ddebs.ubuntu.com

Tags: 14.04, debugging

I downloaded a file:

```
wget http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic-dbgsym_3.19.0-65.73_i386.ddeb
```

dpkg-deb -x barf on that one.

How to report this in order to get it fixed and hopefully obtain this debuginfos?
<sub><sub>[Debug Symbol Packages - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages)</sub></sub>

==========================================

As requested by moderators, I publish here the exact sequence I got on my machine. This is an attempt to obtain kernel debug infos for a given vmcore.

```
CX08$ wget http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic-dbgsym_3.19.0-65.73_i386.ddeb

--2016-08-09 12:12:22--  http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic-dbgsym_3.19.0-65.73_i386.ddeb
Resolving ...:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 245116176 (234M)
Saving to: 'linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic-dbgsym_3.19.0-65.73_i386.ddeb'

linux-image-3.19.0- 100%[===================>] 233.76M  6.10MB/s in 49s

2016-08-09 12:13:12 (4.73 MB/s) - 'linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic-dbgsym_3.19.0-65.73_i386.ddeb' saved [245116176/245116176]


CX08$ dpkg-deb -x linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic-dbgsym_3.19.0-65.73_i386.ddeb \
      yo

dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'linux-image-3.19.0-65-generic-dbgsym_3.19.0-65.73_i386.ddeb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2
```

I double check that lib LZMA is there

```
CX08$ dpkg -l | grep lzma
ii  liblzma5:amd64 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2  amd64 XZ-format compression library
ii  lzma 9.22-2ubuntu2  amd64 Compression and decompression in the LZMA format - command line utility
```

Dunno what to add to make it clearer, I need a debug infos for this version, other version works, but this one barf.

If one can explain either what I am doing wrong, or what process to follow to report this. I reported it here as a first attempt.

Comment: I am a beginner regarding ubuntu organisation, I don't know yet if I should post the request here or in a mailing list. Trying here first :)

Comment: As requested, I gave more detail in the question.

Comment: It somewhat confirm that I am not alone with this, then the file is probably damaged on ubuntu.com. I wonder if there is a process to report this, may be a bugzilla? I am a beginner regarding ubuntu distro.

Comment: Can we hope to get it fixed ?